# Registers command not working in Vim Extension for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am using the [Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) extension for VSCode.
In normal mode when I type `:reg` to access the registers, I instead am given a pop-up text window in VSCode and the registers don't show up.

What is the issue here and how can I solve it?

I was expecting the list of registers to show up in a small window or something similar (as it does in Vim on Linux).

Comment: Facing the same issue